# Extract text according to delimiters but miss out missing entries

Tags: r

I have some text as follows:

```
 inputString<- “Patient Name:MRS Comfor Atest Date of Birth:23/02/1981 Hospital Number:000000 Date of Procedure:01/01/2010 Endoscopist:Dr. Sebastian Zeki: Nurses:Anthony Nurse , Medications:Medication A 50 mcg, Another drug 2.5 mg Instrument:D111 Extent of Exam:second part of duodenum Visualization:Good Tolerance:  Good Complications:  None Co-morbidity:None INDICATIONS FOR EXAMINATION Illness Stomach pain. PROCEDURE PERFORMED Gastroscopy (OGD) FINDINGS Things found and biopsied  DIAGNOSIS Biopsy of various RECOMMENDATIONS Chase for histology. FOLLOW UP Return Home"
```

I want to extract parts of the test in to their own columns according to some text boundaries I have set:

```
  myWords<-c("Patient Name","Date of Birth","Hospital Number","Date of Procedure","Endoscopist","Second Endoscopist","Trainee","Referring Physician","Nurses"."Medications")
```

Not all of the delimiter words are in the text (but they are always in the same order).

I have a function that should separate them out (with the column title as the start of the word boundary:

```
delim<-myWords
inputStringdf <- data.frame(inputString,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  inputStringdf <- inputStringdf %>%
    tidyr::separate(inputString, into = c("added_name",delim),
                    sep = paste(delim, collapse = "|"),
                    extra = "drop", fill = "right")
```

However, when there is no finding between two delimiters, or if the delimiters do not exist, rather than place NA in  the column, it just fills it with the next text found between two delimiters. How can I make sure that the correct columns are filled with the correct text as defined by the delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input shown in the Note at the end transform it into DCF format and then read it in using `read.dcf` which converts the input lines into a character matrix `m`.  See `?read.dcf` for more info. No packages are used.

```
pat <- sprintf("(%s)", paste(myWords, collapse = "|"))
g <- gsub(pat, "\n\\1", paste0(Lines, "\n"))
m <- read.dcf(textConnection(g))
```

Here are the first three columns:

```
m[, 1:3]
##      Patient Name       Date of Birth Hospital Number
## [1,] "MRS Comfor Atest" "23/02/1981"  "000000"       
## [2,] "MRS Comfor Atest" NA            "000000"
```

### Note

The input is assumed to have one record per patient like this example which has two records.  We have just repeated the first patient for simplicity in synthesizing an input data set except we have omitted the Date of Birth in the second record.

```
Lines <- c(inputString, sub("Date of Birth:23/02/1981 ", "", inputString))
```

Comment: Thanks @GGrothendieck. I get the error Error in read.dcf(textConnection(g)) : 
  Line starting 'SP-11-22222 ...' is malformed! using a slightly different dataset. I've googled the error but not sure what a malformed line might be referring to. Any ideas?

Comment: Presumably your input is not in the form shown in the question.  I don't have your input so you will have to determine how it differs.

Comment: Thanks @GGrothendieck. I read up a bit more about read.dcf. Am I right in saying that the delimiters always need to have a colon after them. This is not always the case for my input. Does this mean read.dcf can't be used?

Comment: Use `gsub` to add missing colons.  Add a colon after each tag in the input and then replace double colons with one colon.

Comment: Thanks @GGRothendieck, This is certainly an interesting solution. I have got it to work with my (not shown) dataset. The tags need certain preparation such as making sure there is a colon and a space after each tag and getting rid of brackets and '. This makes me a bit nervous but as it works the points are yours unless anyone can think of an alternative which doesnt need the same preparation